# How to parse HTML response in android

Tags: android, http-post, httpresponse, androidhttpclient

I am sending data to server using HttpPost in android which is successfully received by server. Now the server response is as follows:

```
<html><body>
<input type="text" id="nameL" name="nameL" value="Sam" />
<input type="text" id="level" name="level" value="Introductory"  />
</body></html>
```

How can I get value of http response using the input `name` attribute (e.g. nameL & level) on an Android client?
I am able to get the string response but it contains all tags `<html>....</html>` (as above) in one string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an HTML parser. I personally like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/):

```
Document doc = JSoup.parse(responseString);
String nameL = doc.select("input[name=nameL]").attr("value");
String level = doc.select("input[name=level]").attr("value");
```

However, as [VenomVendor pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20583036/2948765), it is unusual (and inefficient, by the way) to use HTML for API-like communication.

Answer (score -2):

Either generate JSON or XML response from server side.
Use [XML Parsing](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) or [JSON PARSING](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) to retrieve data.

your current response will be useful, only when you are adding the response to [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: But how can we parse this response?